# Simple Akka integer list adder with actors

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying hard to solve this exercise but I cannot find a way to make it work, even after copying examples from the Akka website (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html).

I need to basically just split a List of integers into n partitions, give each partition to each n actor, let the actor sum all their values and finally return a message to the parent actor with the result, which will add it to an accumulator variable. I don't need to do anything fancy like logging, fault-tolerence, performance optimizitation whatsoever etc.

```
import AdderMain.StartJob
import AdderWorker.ProcessDone
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.{ActorContext, Behaviors, LoggerOps}
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Behavior}

object AdderWorker {
    final case class Process(replyTo: ActorRef[ProcessDone], payloadPartition: List[Int])
    final case class ProcessDone(result: Int)

    def apply(): Behaviors.Receive[Process] =
        Behaviors.receiveMessage[Process] {
            case Process(replyTo, payloadPartition) =>
                println(s"Worker is processing data...")
                val result = sumListElements(payloadPartition)
                replyTo ! ProcessDone(result)
                Behaviors.same
        }

    private def sumListElements(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
        case Nil => 0
        case x :: xs => x + sumListElements(xs)
    }
}

object AdderMain extends App {

    final case class StartJob(payload: List[Int])

    def apply(payload: List[Int]): Behavior[ProcessDone] =
        Behaviors.setup { context =>
            val payloadPartitions: List[List[Int]] = payload.grouped(4).toList
            payloadPartitions.foreach { l =>
                val worker = context.spawn(AdderWorker(), "Stuff")
                worker ! AdderWorker.Process(context.self, l)
            }

            Behaviors.receiveMessage { message =>
                println(s"Done ${message}")
                Behaviors.same
            }
        }

    val payload = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)

    val system: ActorSystem[AdderMain.StartJob] = ActorSystem(AdderMain(payload), "AdderMain")
}
```

As you can see `AdderMain` spawns a `AdderWorker` for each List partition and sends a "Process" message containing the List. The error I'm getting is

```
Error:(45, 72) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.actor.typed.Behavior[AdderWorker.ProcessDone]
 required: akka.actor.typed.Behavior[Product with java.io.Serializable]
Note: AdderWorker.ProcessDone <: Product with java.io.Serializable, but class Behavior is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
    val system: ActorSystem[AdderMain.StartJob] = ActorSystem(AdderMain(payload), "AdderMain")
```

but it seems like it stems from bigger problems in my code... feel free to correct me as much as you want I just got started with Scala, Akka and functional programming.

P.S.: I haven't accumulated the results any variable yet

EDIT: Here's a working solution

```
import java.util.UUID

import AdderWorker.ProcessDone
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Behavior}
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.{ActorContext, Behaviors, LoggerOps}


object AdderWorker {
    final case class Process(replyTo: ActorRef[ProcessDone], payloadPartition: List[Int])
    final case class ProcessDone(result: Int)

    def apply(): Behaviors.Receive[Process] =
        Behaviors.receiveMessage[Process] {
            case Process(replyTo, payloadPartition) =>
                println(s"Worker is processing data...")
                val result = sumListElements(payloadPartition)
                replyTo ! ProcessDone(result)
                Behaviors.stopped
        }

    private def sumListElements(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
        case Nil => 0
        case x :: xs => x + sumListElements(xs)
    }
}

object BasicAdder extends App {
    var counter = 0
    var max = 0
    var sum = 0

    final case class StartJob(payload: List[Int])

    def apply(payload: List[Int]): Behavior[ProcessDone] =
        Behaviors.setup { context =>
            val payloadPartitions: List[List[Int]] = payload.grouped(4).toList
            max = payloadPartitions.size

            payloadPartitions.foreach { l =>
                val worker = context.spawn(AdderWorker(), UUID.randomUUID.toString)

                // Send the Process message to the newly spawned worker
                // providing a reference to the guardian actor and a partition of the payload
                worker ! AdderWorker.Process(context.self, l)
            }

            Behaviors.receiveMessage { message =>
                // this is thread-safe
                sum += message.result
                counter += 1

                if (counter < max) {
                    println(s"Current sum: ${sum}")
                    Behaviors.same
                } else {
                    println(s"Final sum: ${sum}")
                    Behaviors.stopped
                }
            }
        }

        val payload = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100) // result should be 550

    val system: ActorSystem[AdderWorker.ProcessDone] = ActorSystem(BasicAdder(payload), "AdderMain")
}
```

Comment: from the looks of it , these 2 types are invariant 
ActorSystem[AdderMain.StartJob] = ActorSystem(AdderMain(payload))
instead of [AdderMain.StartJob] it should be ActorSystem[AdderWorker.ProcessDone]

Comment: Thanks that solved it. So if I understand well the type parameter of ActorSystem should match the type parameter of the Behavior object returned with the apply function of the guardian object passed to said ActorSystem, is this correct?

Comment: Yes,Like all type ascriptions , the value must be the same type or subtype